# amchart 4 chart not loading when angular 5 prod build taken

Tags: angular, open-source, amcharts, amcharts4

Working on a POC of amchart 4 with angular 5 application. I am able to load chart and implement the required charts on my local machine. Wanted to demo it to management so I took angular build(prod build-dist folder one) and deployed it to on server.

The charts are not getting loaded on this environment. What could be the possible issue?

Does amChart 4 not allow to take PROD build of angular for their free version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you check the console logs

Comment: @JithinPariyarath no error/warning on console, even the chunk for module in which the amchart is loaded.

Comment: Did you set `--build-optimizer=false` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/integrations/using-angular2/)?

Comment: @xorspark yes it is set already and still same issue of not loading the graph